# How do I get first 1 or 2 characters of a string until a number appears in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a postcode field and want to only get the first letters that appear before a number appears.  e.g. E11 would return E, HD4, would return HD.

Comment: Can you answer my question instead of questioning my knowledge of your problem?

Comment: What are you asking?  HDE5 isn't a postcode.

Comment: Bear in mind Nicola, that the second half of British postcodes always end NLL, but the first can be LN, LLN, LNL (eg some in London), LNN, LLNN and maybe others. Where L is a letter, and N a number.

Comment: I'm asking if you have a postcode that could be different.  Further since you never specified what country it is even more difficult to answer your question.

Comment: You didn't ask that.  You just said "what about HDE5?".  I couldn't infer from that what HDE5 was nor, what you were asking about it.

Answer (score 2):

Use **regex** to find the position of the first number

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

and then use **substring** to get from 0 to this number

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php

Comment: So something like `SUBSTRING(p.Major, p.Major REGEXP '/^\D*(?=\d)/'-1, p.Major REGEXP '/^\D*(?=\d)/'-1)`

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps . . .

```
SELECT IF (postcode REGEXP "^[A-Z][A-Z]",LEFT(postcode,2),LEFT(postcode,1));
```

These examples demonstrate:

```
SELECT IF ("H5 7PL" REGEXP "^[A-Z][A-Z]",LEFT("H5 7PL",2),LEFT("H5 7PL",1));
-> "H"

SELECT IF ("HD5 7PL" REGEXP "^[A-Z][A-Z]",LEFT("HD5 7PL",2),LEFT("HD5 7PL",1));
-> "HD"
```

Comment: That is helpful, thank you.  However, I need to join a table onto the value.  So I don't want use an if, I just want to say `LEFT JOIN postcode ON postcode.[first 1 or 2 chars from postcode] = address.postcode1`